# What is the "creator code" for Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: appleevents, finalcut

I'm working on sending Apple Events to Final Cut Pro X. At the moment I have the trial (free is always nice for experimenting).  However, looking at the .plist in the package, the creator code is specified as "????" and its bundle ID is "com.apple.FinalCutTrial".  I found the creator code for FCP 7 is "KeyG" but nothing regarding FCPX specifically.

For the events themselves, I'm also looking for what events it supports.  The "MovieAssembler" sample from Apple is dated 11-2007 and lists Final Cut Pro 5.x. I've thrown some events at FCPX trial, but I get back an event with key 'errn' and a long whose lower word translates to -1708, "error apple event not handled" (seems more than coincidental). They also have an FxPlug architecture, but that's aimed at video.

Which leaves me with a couple questions:

1. What is the creator code for Final Cut Pro X?  Seeing that it isn't backwards-compatible with the project files, I suspect there's a chance the code changed.
2. Can anyone point me to examples/documentation about the Apple Events that FCP X supports?

I have an Apple Developer account, so can get to resources on their site (if I know where it is!)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes looking...

1. Turns out that Final Cut Pro X has *no* creator code. Just like the trial, its CFBundleSignature (OS Type Code) is '????'. Its Bundle ID is "com.apple.FinalCut" (slightly different from the trial).
2. FCP X does not support Apple Events anymore. It appears to respond to the generic "open file" event, though I expect that's because Cocoa/AppKit routes the request through the app delegate `-application:openFile:` method.